# Struts property file value not printing properly

Tags: struts2

Hi i am using struts2 and hibernate in my project. When i am trying to print messages from property file the value is not printing instead its key is displaying

I have set `salesMan.login.ErrorMessage=Invalid Username` or Password in my `mydrdirect.prperties` file and also i have set  `<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="myDrDirect" />`. But when i call the getText function from action file the value print in the browser is `salesMan.login.ErrorMessage`. Anybody have idea about it?

Comment: Is your property file in the CLASSPATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1**: If the key you are using to get the value will not match with the key you provided in the property file, then it will display the "key" in the browser.

**Case 2**: ***mydrdirect.prperties***
 is this correct file name?

Comment: The name of the file was mydrdirect.properties. The value of the salesMan.login.ErrorMessage is in the property file i have check it and also it is working in my localhost

Comment: Ok i got it some issue with property file. The property file eas not fully uploded last time. I have upload it agin retsrt the server, the issue cleared. Thanks.